# NSDateFormatter will not parse string with timezone that includes colon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, parsing, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to transform `@"Fri, 26 Aug 2011 10:51:00 +02:00"` into an `NSDate`:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

I get `nil` as a result; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The colon in the timezone (`+02:00`) is the issue. According to the [Unicode Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns), the timezone should be `+0200`.

Comment: In line with your date incorrectly recorded UTC, there should be no separator hours and minutes.

Comment: My string is standard... I cannot change it

Comment: I've had to occasionally do a bit of string manipulation like in the first comment to work with NSDateFormatter. You can of course copy the string and modify it to follow the standard.

Comment: Not sure that this solution is optimal, but if you get string with this format, you can cut any ':' from it by metod [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""]; and get date from it with format @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HHmmss Z"

Comment: You can specify ZZZZZ for the timezone, that will parse it correctly even with the colon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colon in the timezone `(+02:00)` is the issue. According to the [Unicode Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns), 1..3 capital Z pattern denotes a [RFC 822 time zone](http://asg.web.cmu.edu/rfc/rfc822.html#sec-5.1). RFC 822 time zones represent the offset from GMT (or UTC) and have the following format:

```
zone             =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                 ...
                 ...
                 / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                                 ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

As you can see, there is no colon between hours and minutes of the time zone. Therefore, the time zone should be `+0200`.

The most proper solution would be to generate a  unicode compliant date string in the first place, but if you are stuck with this format, you may need to preprocess the date string before you pass it to `NSDateFormatter`.

For example, a quick fix would be using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` to get rid of the colon in the time zone:

```
// dateString --> Fri, 26 Aug 2011 10:51:00 +02:00
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" 
                                                   withString:@"" 
                                                      options:0
                                                        range:NSMakeRange(25, [dateString length] - 25)];
// dateString --> Fri, 26 Aug 2011 10:51:00 +0200
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
// date --> 2011-08-26 08:51:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the getObjectValue:forString:range:error: method to parse dates that have the colon in the timezone:

```
// test date formatting
NSString *dateString = @"2012-04-11T18:34:19+00:00";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
NSDate *date;
NSError *error;
[formatter getObjectValue:&date forString:dateString range:nil error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2):

No string manipulation required. Change your format string to:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z:00"];
```

I tested it and it parses the date you give just fine. When I print the date using [NSDate description], I get **2011-08-26 08:51:00 +0000**, which is equivalent to the date given in the string.

Comment: There are timezones that are not even hours such as +05:30 in India so this is not a good general solution.

Comment: True, and it was never meant to be, but it may meet the needs of the OP and it's easier than removing characters from strings.

Comment: Doesn't work, results in 2016-11-01T00:00:00-0700:00

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a common problem.  A number of servers produce the date with the colon in the timezone, and NSDateFormatter can't (to my knowledge) be convinced to accept it.  The solution is to cut out the colon somehow, as suggested.